# How to make vertical menu with emenu extension in Yii?

Tags: menu, yii, css

Using the [emenu](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/emenu/) Yii extension for a menu.  The underlying project for this extension is http://lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/ .

Right now the sub menus display in a row (which does eventually wrap to a 2nd row). I'm using the "nvidia" theme.

[image: menu example]

How do I make submenus vertical?  I want the items in the sub menu to stack vertically on top of one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a css issue. The inner `<ul>` should have the style: `width : 100%` which comes from *dropdown.css*, but it is being overridden by *themes/nvidia.com/default.css* where it is specified as: `width: 170px`. So you can change that value back to `100%` by adding it in your own custom css file.

*dropdown.css*:

```css
ul.dropdown ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
```

*themes/nvidia.com/default.css*:

```css
ul.dropdown ul {
  width: 170px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: none;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  -moz-opacity: .9;
  KhtmlOpacity: .9;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

*mystyle.css*:

```css
ul.dropdown ul{
  width:100% !important;
}
```